# jQuery Vertical Dropdown w/ Fade

Tags: jquery, slide, fade

This works. However, clicking the "#pages-btn" again doesn't close "#instruct-pages" div. Is there a better way to write this? Thanks for the help.

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/PCzfs/1/

```
$("#pages-btn").click(function () {
    $("#instruct-pages").fadeToggle();
    $(this).addClass("options-active");
});
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("#instruct-pages");
    if (!container.is(e.target)
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        container.fadeOut();
        $("#pages-btn").removeClass("options-active");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $instructPages = $("#instruct-pages");
$instructPages.is(":visible") ? $instructPages.fadeOut() : $instructPages.fadeIn();
```

[***demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/tCvDD/)

---

***Updated***:

> How would you toggle the .options-active class for "click"? It works
>   when you click outside the container but doesn't work if you click the
>   actual button.

```
var $instructPages = $("#instruct-pages");
if ($instructPages.is(":visible"))
{
    $instructPages.fadeOut();
    $(this).removeClass("options-active");
}
else
{
    $instructPages.fadeIn();
    $(this).addClass("options-active");
}
```

[***demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/bJyBe/)

Comment: How would you toggle the .options-active class for "click"? It works when you click outside the container but doesn't work if you click the actual button. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/PCzfs/2/

```
$("#pages-btn").click(function (e) {
     var container = $("#instruct-pages");
    container.fadeToggle();        

    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0){
        if($(this).hasClass('options-active')){
            $("#pages-btn").removeClass("options-active");    
        }else{
            $("#pages-btn").addClass("options-active");
        }   

    }

});
```

Comment: This works but disables clicking outside of the container. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this to your mouseup function:

```
e.target.id!=="pages-btn"
```